# Git clone/pull using PHP on a shared hosting

Tags: php, git, github, shared-hosting

I have a github repo, and I have a shared hosting account which runs PHP.

My goal is to clone/download the latest files on my github repo to my hosting account using PHP so it is kind of like a deploy.

My hosting account does not and can not have git installed. Also it cannot run exec or shell because it is a shared hosting account and they forbid these kind of PHP functions.

Therefore I want to ask, is there a PHP script that can clone everything from my github repo and put it on my shared hosting using github API? I googled a bit and could only find examples that actually runs "git pull" or "git clone" on the server using exec() or similar functions (which my hosting account forbids).

Any ideas appreciated, thanks!

Comment: That's pretty terrible hosting, even for shared hosting. You might be better off finding a better hosting company.

Comment: Although I'm with @Michael that it might be worthwhile to look at a better hosting option, I'm assuming you have FTP access? What about something like FTPloy? https://ftploy.com/ (I have no association with them)

Comment: Ftploy looks like an option but i am looking for a solution that i control. Thanks anyway, its a possible alternative.